# Can I get ride of dichlorobenzene in honey?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, food-chemistry, toxicity

I have some honey that was stored near dichlorobenzene crystals & has taken on the smell. I'm wondering if I turn it into mead if it would remove the chemical?

The procedure would be to add 5-10 parts water to the honey. Then boil the solution for at least an hour. I would think this should rapidly remove the benzine component.

The second part of the process would to be to add a yeast culture that would not ferment until the chlorine has dissipated.

It would seem that I could tell the chemical is absent when the strong odor is gone.

Comment: I would get rid of that honey without a second thought.

Comment: Odor may be gone but it still may be dangerous.

Comment: Activated charcoal might work (after diluting the honey with water), but still, I wouldn't consume that.

Answer (score 4):

Just theoretically, if you were to heat the honey ([primarily fructose and glucose](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/webprojects2001/loveridge/index-page3.html)) to 373 K, the boiling point of water, it would speed up the evaporation of the dichlorobenzene ([vapor pressure ~8,000 Pa](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C95501&Mask=4&Type=ANTOINE&Plot=on)). That might be enough to get rid of the odor, if kept at that temperature for a few days.

That said, the flavor of the honey would likely be destroyed, as well. Even though pasteurization of honey is not normally recommended, that only requires heating to [145° F (336 K) for 30 minutes](https://honeybeesuite.com/honey-pasteurization/), and it still changes the flavor.

So toss the honey, or use it as an [embalming agent](http://historybuff.com/was-alexander-great-really-buried-in-giant-vat-honey-EZgXDzoEqjYG) (see also [National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/projects/out-of-eden-walk/articles/2015-05-honey-im-dead/)). The dichlorobenzene "moth flakes" should make this honey even more effective!